# How to prevent assignment to backing fields?

Tags: c#

I have the following property and backing field:

```
    private Vector3 _positionB;
    public Vector3 PositionB
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nodeB == null) return _positionB;
            else return _nodeB.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            _positionB = value;
            UpdateMesh();
        }
    }
```

Problem is, I some times keep assigning the value to the backing field in my class and skipping over the property setter (thus it doesn't update automatically due to logic error).

I would much rather enforce assignment via the property so that the setter runs the relevant function afterwards.

Is there anyway to abstract this out to enforce assignment to only the property within the class?

Comment: You could create a derived class but it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that any other member of the class will always have equal access to any `private` field (as you cannot have a class-level field that's scoped to a property), [the only thing you can really do is (ab)use `ObsoleteAttribute` to trigger a compiler warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618).

- Use `#pragma warning disable 0618` to suppress the compiler warning only when appropriate (i.e. inside the `PositionB` property).
- You cannot use the `Obsolete(String,Boolean)` constructor to set `bool error == true` because you cannot suppress errors, you can only suppress compiler Information messages and Warnings.
- However (I think) you can set the `.csproj` project properties to promote warning 618 to an error, but this applies to *all* occurrences of CS0618 instead of only this particular C# field.

  - In VS, go Project > Properties > Build > "Treat warnings as errors" and add "618" to the textbox (multiple values are separated by commas or semicolons)
  - Or edit your `.csproj` file directly in Notepad and add this to your main `<PropertyGroup>` element:

    ```
    <WarningsAsErrors>618</WarningsAsErrors>
    ```

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    [Obsolete( "Do not use this field directly. Use the " + nameof(Foo.PositionB) + " property instead." )]
    private Vector3 position3;

    public Vector3 PositionB
    {
        get
        {
            #pragma warning disable 618 // Obsolete
            if( this.nodeB == null ) return this.positionB;
            else return this.nodeB.Position;
            #pragma warning restore 618
        }
        set
        {
            #pragma warning disable 618 // Obsolete
            this.positionB = value;
            this.UpdateMesh();
            #pragma warning restore 618
        }
    }
}
```

So this code will cause a compiler warning:

```
class Foo
{
    // [...]

    public void Bar()
    {
        this.positionB = 123; // this statement will cause a compiler warning
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- As an alternative to `Obsolete` (see my other answer) another option is to define a custom type that *encapsulates* the behaviour of your `PositionB` property.
- You can use a `struct` or `class` but I recommend using a `struct` to eliminate the overhead of having another GC object on the heap and [the performance hit of a cache-miss due to reference-locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).
- And because the backing field is `readonly` (but it contains a mutable field) it becomes impossible for other members of your class to overwrite the field directly.

  - (Remember that `readonly` does not mean "immutable" and note that C# does not support C++-style "const-correctness".)

Like so:

```
class Foo
{
    private struct Vector3Wrapper
    {
        private readonly Foo foo;

        private Vector3 value;

        public Vector3Wrapper( Foo foo )
        {
            this.foo   = foo;
            this.value = default;
        }

        public Vector3 GetValue()
        {
            //return this.foo.nodeB == null ? this.value : this.foo.nodeB.Position;
            return this.foo.nodeB?.Position ?? this.value; // <-- more succinct!
        }

        public void SetValue( Vector3 value )
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly Vector3Wrapper positionB;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.positionB = new Vector3Wrapper( this );
    }

    public Vector3 PositionB
    {
        get => this.positionB.GetValue();
        set
        {
            this.positionB.SetValue( value );
            this.UpdateMesh();
        }
    }
}
```

So this code will cause a compile-time error:

```
class Foo
{
    // [...]

    void Baz()
    {
        this.positionb = default; // will error because `this.positionB` is readonly (but not immutable)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use automatic properties:

```
public Vector3 PositionB { get; set; }
```

This will prevent you from ever assigning a value to the private backing field, upgrades readability and makes code more robust; since you always use the property to assign value.

However when you want to do something with the value, you might want to make it `get;` only, so you can do custom setting in a public method of your class, depending if you want to call the setter from outside your class.

Comment: This does not answer the question because auto-properties in C# cannot have custom get/set logic which the OP is using in their posted code. Also, I disagree that using auto-properties makes code "more robust" - because after converting an auto-property to a property+backing-field the codebase still runs the risk of unintentionally accessing or mutating the backing-field instead of going through the property.

Comment: Yep, let’s get rid of that property backing field and make it auto property. In that case you always have to set it via property but you have to always make the step of going through an additional setup first: via a function (like in java). 
Your solution of a struct is a good solution too though, because they are immutable.

Comment: Again, I don't see how using auto-properties helps in the OP's case because they require custom getter/setter logic. Additionally, structs are not immutable in C#/.NET - the struct example I gave is expressly mutable, in fact.