# How to get C# warning when setting field in class - with Visual Studio or a VS plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I let Visual Studio warn me, when I'm using a field instead of a property setter in the class it is defined?

Are there Visual Studio options or plugins that provide this feature?

```
    public class Person
    {
      private string name; // field
      public string Name   // property
      {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; SomethingImportant();}
      }
    
      public void Init(string newName)
      {
        name = newName; //Accidentally using "name" instead of "Name"
      }
    }
```

For access outside the class the private protection level would stop me from using "name". How can I get the same error when using it inside the class or class extensions?

Please note:
This is not a duplicate of: [How to prevent assignment to backing fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872566/how-to-prevent-assignment-to-backing-fields)
The solution provided in that question is a hack/workaround using the compiler.
I'm asking for plugins or an IDE solution to achieve that.

Comment: But technically this is fine :) If there is some logic behind, this assignment should come up during code review :)

Comment: This sounds like something that the [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)  plugin for Visual Studio could be configured to do. I am not sure though (which is why I am commenting, and not answering).

Comment: You could write an analyzer for that.